# Unescape and get Unicode String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a text file with the string,

```
Here is some Bengali letter : \u00E0\u00A6\u00A6\u00E0\u00A7\u0080
```

which is supposed to represent the string,

```
Here is some Bengali letter : দী
```

I am very confused about the encoding/decoding here. I have tried to convert the string back-n-forth by getting the byte array, I have tried StringEscapeUtils as suggested in a few posts here! But all of them produced garbled string.

My best guess is that the Unicode part "দী" is URLEncoded to,

```
%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%80
```

and then somehow converted to the string,

```
\u00E0\u00A6\u00A6\u00E0\u00A7\u0080
```

So my question is how to read the file and get the desired string in Kotlin?

Comment: This looks like classic [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake): something took an UTF-8 string and assumed it was Latin-1 and that it needed to be converted to UTF-8. Once you understand this, the process of reversing it should be obvious and trivial. Here's how you'd do it in Python: `text = text.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Actually, this letter should be represented as `\u09A6\u09C0`

Comment: @tripleee Thank you! I managed un-mojibake the situation by setting `str = String(str.toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))` in my Kotlin project.

Comment: I could not find an existing duplicate, so probably post that as an answer (and eventually accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering to close the question)

As suggested by @tripleee, the issue was solved by encoding the string to Latin-1 and then decoding to UTF-8.

Here's an MWE in Kotlin

```
val originalStr = "Here is some Bengali letter : \u00E0\u00A6\u00A6\u00E0\u00A7\u0080"
val str = String(originalStr.toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))
println(str)

Output> Here is some Bengali letter : দী
```